# emaiiRegular Expression (Regex) python

Tags: python, regex, email

I'd like to get the best regex for emails, the efficient one?

any help?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

here is the official regex of what an email looks like

```
 \A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*
 |  "(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]
      |  \\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")
@ (?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
  |  \[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
       (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:
          (?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]
          |  \\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)
     \])\z
```

see: RFC 5322

that said you can probably get away with

`(\w+\@\w+)` or even `email.count("@") == 1`

here is a very nice article about validating email addresses : http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html  in fact its the first link that google brings up if you search for `email regex`

Comment: your pattern isn't clear, can you please rewrite it?

Comment: The pattern is clear - what, specifically, do you not understand?